# I need to create a number pattern program in C for my school assignment. Pattern- 1 141 14941

Tags: c, numbers, pattern-matching

The pattern is

___1

__141

_14941

I have tried to some extent but looks like i have created a odd number pattern program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, N=3;

    for(i=1; i<=N; i++)
    {
        // Prints the first part of pattern
        for(j=1; j<=(i*2)-1; j+=2)
        {
            printf("%d", j);
        }

        // Prints the second part of pattern
        for(j=(i-1)*2-1; j>=1; j-=2)
        {
            printf("%d", j);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I can see that the pattern has numbers that are off by odd numbers such as 3 and 5 respectively.
But i cant seem to grasp exactly how to do it.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The pattern could also be squares of the natural number sequence (1^2 = **1**, 2^2= **4** , 3^2 = **9** , etc.). Maybe consider that.

Comment: What will happen when the pattern encountered 2-digit numbers?

Comment: @silverfox if this is as well-prepared as academia has exhibited in recent years, the thought may never have crossed the mind of the prof/ta that derived this assignment.

Comment: @WhozCraig 4^2 = 16 ... how does that go with the 4 coming next in the sequence?

Comment: Thanks to @WhozCraig! I have completed my assignment successfully.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, N=3;

    for(i=1; i<=N; i++)
    {
        // Prints the first part of pattern
        for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            int b=pow(j,2);
            printf("%d", b);
        }

        // Prints the second part of pattern
        for(j=(i-1); j>=1; j--)
        {
            int b=pow(j,2);
            printf("%d", b);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

Comment: Your odd number thing also works (for the given examples...): `(let* ((n 5)
  (up (cons 1
     (loop
       with x = 1
       for o from 3 to n by 2
       collecting (+ x o)
       do (setf x (+ x o))))))
    (append up (rest (reverse up))))` -> `(1 4 9 4 1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j, N=3;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        //For printing Spaces
        for(int sp=0;sp<N-i;sp++){
            printf(" ");
        }

        /*For printing the numbers 
        from left till the middle column*/
        for(int j=1;j<=i+1;j++){
            printf("%d",j*j);
        }

        /*For printing the numbers 
        from the strict right to the middle column 
        and till the end*/
        for(int j=1;j<i+1;j++){
            printf("%d",j*j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```